# Oracle Contains is not working

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column in my table that is context indexed.

```
CREATE INDEX CIDX_MUSTFIXBY ON TABLE
  (MUST_FIX_BY)
INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT
NOPARALLEL;
```

And i am trying a query with where condition

> AND must_fix_by LIKE 'Q2%'

and it returns rows.

However when i try query with where condition

> AND contains(must_fix_by, 'Q2') > 0

and it does not return any rows.

Can somebody please tell me why like is working and contains is not?

Comment: What are you trying to achive with the second query?  Do you want a count(contains(must_fix_by,'Q2'))>0 in order to find out how many records contain that string?

Comment: I want the query to return all rows that has Q2 in must_fix_by. I know i can go with LIKE but i want to know why contains doesn't work.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I read the question wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two possible reasons - the index may not be synchronized, and `CONTAINS` seems to match words while `LIKE` matches strings.

An example of two strings, where `LIKE` matches both, but `CONTAINS` matches neither:

```
create table test1(must_fix_by varchar2(4000));
create index cidx_mustfixby on test1(must_fix_by) indextype is ctxsys.context;
insert into test1 values('Q234567');
insert into test1 values('Q2 234567');
select * from test1 where must_fix_by like 'Q2%';

MUST_FIX_BY
-----------
Q234567
Q2 234567

select * from test1 where contains(must_fix_by, 'Q2') > 0;

no rows selected
```

By default, `CONTEXT` indexes need to be [manually synchronized](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/text.112/e24436/csql.htm#sthref182).  You either need to run: `exec ctx_ddl.sync_index('cidx_mustfixby');`, or you need to create you index with `on commit`.

```
exec ctx_ddl.sync_index('cidx_mustfixby');
select * from test1 where contains(must_fix_by, 'Q2') > 0;

MUST_FIX_BY
-----------
Q2 234567
```

This fixes one of the issues.  But `Q234567` is still not matched.  I don't know a lot about Oracle Text, and I can't even find a simple description of how `CONTAINS` works.  But it seems to be based on full words instead of strings.  There needs to be some sort of word boundary
between Q2 and other characters for it to be picked up by a simple `CONTAINS` filter.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to add the % when using CONTAINS.

```
AND contains(must_fix_by, 'Q2%') > 0
```