# Weird behavior of Oracle Text

Tags: oracle, oracle-text

I'm getting a weird behaviour using Oracle Text.
I have created the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_OTEXT_TABLE (id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, text VARCHAR2(200));
```

and populated the table with the following data:

```
1   California is a state in the US.
2   Paris is a city in France.
3   France is in Europe.
4   Italy is a city in Europe.
```

I've then created the index:

```
CREATE INDEX TEST_OTEXT_INDEX ON TEST_OTEXT_TABLE(text)
INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT 
parameters ('DATASTORE CTXSYS.DEFAULT_DATASTORE');

EXEC CTX_DDL.SYNC_INDEX('TEST_OTEXT_INDEX', '2M');
```

If I run

```
select id, score(1) from TEST_OTEXT_TABLE WHERE CONTAINS (text, 'is a city', 1) > 0 ;
```

everything works fine as Oracle Text correctly returns

```
    ID   SCORE(1)
---------- ----------
     2          4
     4          4
```

However, if I run

```
select id, score(1) from TEST_OTEXT_TABLE WHERE CONTAINS (text, 'is a', 1) > 0 ;
```

it returns

```
no rows selected
```

instead of returning the very same result.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15395645/oracle-contains-is-not-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because score is too low:

```
select id, score(1) from TEST_OTEXT_TABLE WHERE CONTAINS (text, 'is a', 1) = 0 ;

Row   ID  SCORE
1     1   0
2     2   0
3     3   0
4     4   0
```

If you use city the score is 4 and results are shown:

```
select id, score(1) from TEST_OTEXT_TABLE WHERE CONTAINS (text, 'city', 1) > 0 ;
```

More info about score:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/text.901/a90121/csql8.htm

Here you can read how score algoritm works:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/text.901/a90121/ascore2.htm

Comment: Why the score is `0` even if the row contains the searched word (i.e. `is a`) ? And why the score is higher if I search `a city` ?

Comment: Got it: terms like `is` and `a` are "noise terms" and therefore scored low (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/text.901/a90121/ascore2.htm).

Answer (score 1):

is a are stopwords, that means they do not bear relevancy for a text
they're likely not indexed at all
you can edit the stopword list and remove words that you want to be indexed